# scraping/identifying a table from a website that has <div tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to extract a dynamic table from a website (https://datagolf.org/performance-table) using BeautifulSoup. However, when I use the `soup.find()` command to find the source code of the table, nothing appears on the output. Here's the code I'm using:

```
url = 'https://datagolf.org/performance-table'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
box = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table-div'})
box
```

The output for the code above shows:

```
<div class="table-div">
</div>
```

When I changed the class to `class_='table'` then the output shows blank. Any thoughts on what's going on here? Could it be that I'm calling for the incorrect source code?

Comment: It seems that the website uses JavaScript, and Beautiful Soup doesn't support JavaScript.

You might want to use Selenium

Comment: Try looking for an API in, if it's dynamic it can be a case of an API being used to create the contents of that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with beautiful Soup but it didn't work but it works with Selenium. 
I made a code for that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://datagolf.org/performance-table")
l = []
l1 = []

#a = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table')
#print(a.text) # this will print all of the table content

b = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('datahead')
for d in b:
    l1.append(d.text)

l1.pop(5)    
l.append(l1)


c = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('datarow')
l1 = []
for d in c:
    e = d.text
    e = e.split('\n')
    l.append(e)

print(l) # this will print table as a list
driver.close()
```

Comment: had to change webdriver.Firefox to Chrome but other than that this works great! thank you

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored within the page in Json format, you can use `re`/`json` module to parse the data.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://datagolf.org/performance-table'
txt = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r"var reload_data = JSON\.parse\('(.*?)'", txt).group(1))

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
for row in data['data']['2020']['table']:
    print('{:<40} {}'.format(row['player_name'], row['wins']))
```

Prints:

```
McIlroy, Rory                            1.0
Hatton, Tyrrell                          1.0
Rahm, Jon                                0.0
Thomas, Justin                           2.0
Schauffele, Xander                       0.0
Matsuyama, Hideki                        1.0
Reed, Patrick                            1.0
Woods, Tiger                             1.0

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: The format of the data is following:

```
...
            {
                "amateur": 0,
                "app_raw": 0.9807287716094194,
                "app_true": 1.1416339999999998,
                "arg_raw": 0.30359835879467356,
                "arg_true": 0.35591150000000005,
                "dg_id": 10091,
                "events": 8,
                "exp_major_wins": 0.0,
                "exp_pga_wins": 1.5499999999999998,
                "flag": "NIR",
                "ott_raw": 0.699243421907403,
                "ott_true": 0.8408904999999999,
                "player_name": "McIlroy, Rory",
                "putt_raw": 0.07181996378995552,
                "putt_true": 0.16352450000000002,
                "rnds": 29,
                "sg_raw": 2.5018271707385242,
                "sg_true": 2.9106948275862066,
                "shotlink_rnds": 20.0,
                "t2g_raw": 1.983570552311496,
                "t2g_true": 2.3384359999999997,
                "tour": "PGA",
                "wins": 1.0
            },
...
```

you can use keys `app_true`, `putt_true`, `arg_true` etc.

Comment: how would i include other rows as well? i tried ``` print('{:<40} {}'.format(row['player_name'], row['events'], row['wins']))``` but still only prints the 'wins' column.

Comment: @SangwooChun Change the format string: `print('{:<40} {:<40} {}'.format(row['player_name'], row['events'], row['wins']))` (or some other numbers instead of `40`, depends how you want to format it).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! what's the syntax behind {:<40}? When i tried to extract the entire table, the output extracts some integers after each player name so i'm trying to work that out.

Comment: @SangwooChun You can read about string formatting for example here https://pyformat.info/

Comment: none of the 'putt',  'arg',  'app', 'ott', 'total' (all under strokes gained section) are being found in that for loop even with the correct formatting...is there a reason why?

Comment: @SangwooChun Did you try to uncomment the line and see how the data is formatted? I put sample of the data in my edit.